# Python : Bypass Error message from API server

Tags: python, api

I'm using a Python script to get Stock price from an API,
Everythinks works great but sometimes I receive html errors instead of prices,
These errors prevent the script from continuing and the terminal stopped working,
how do I test the response from the API before passing the information to the next script?
I don't want the terminal to stop when it receives server errors.
Only one line to get price :

```
get_price = api_client.quote('TWTR')
```

Comment: What is `api_client`? Please add relevant line where it is defined or imported to your code

Comment: Could you provide us more information of the API that you work in ?

Comment: Error handling? `try` / `except`?

Answer (score 0):

The question, "How do I test the response from the API before passing the information" is well suited for a `try/except` block. For example the following will attempt to call `quote()` and if an exception is raised it will print a message to the console:

```py
try:
    get_price = api_client.quote('TWTR')
except <Exception Type Goes Here>:
    # handle the exception case.
    print('Getting quote did not work as expected')
```

The example is useful for illustrating the point but you should improve the exception handling. I recommend you take a look at resources to help you understand how to appropriately handle exceptions in your code. A few that I have found useful would be:

- [The Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html): Learn what an exception is and how they can be used
- [Python Exception Handling](https://julien.danjou.info/python-exceptions-guide/): A blog post that details how to combine some of the concepts in the Python documentation practically.